# Simple & Compounded Interest with Python; "x and y must have the same first dimensions"

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to generate a a plot demonstrating the difference between simple and compounded interest. The problem I'm having is that I get an error: "x and y must have same first dimension". I've seem similar issues on here etc, but I'm having troubles transferring those solutions to my actual problem. I've looked at the size/length of t and fv_2 and fv_3 and the dimensions all match; fv_1 is just a straight line (see code).

If there's anyone who might know where I'm going wrong, advice, suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


pv=1000
r=0.08
n=10

t=np.linspace(0,n,n)
fv_1=np.ones(len(t)*pv) #horizontal line 
fv_2=pv*(1+r*t) #simple interest
fv_3=pv*pow(1+r,t) #compounded interest


plt.title("Simple vs. Compounded Interest Rate")
plt.xlabel("Number of Years, t")
plt.ylabel("Pounds Sterling, £")
plt.xlim(0,11)
plt.ylim(800,2200)
plt.plot(t,fv_1,'b-')
plt.plot(t,fv_2,'g--')
plt.plot(t,fv_3,'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Also note that t=np.linspace(0,n,n) does gives you non-exact years since you are trying to get 10 values between 0 and 10 (inclusive at both ends). You will get 0.0, 1.1111, 2.2222 etc... Using t=np.linspace(0,n,n+1) for example gives you 0.0, 1.0, ... 10.0 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
fv_1=np.ones(len(t))*pv
```

Explanation: Your code has `)` at wrong location. In your example, the number of elements in `fv_1` is not equal to the number of elements in `t`. You most likely want the `len(t)` number of elements of value `pv`.

Comment: @Roberto Mena. Hi guys, thanks for helping there. However, I'm now getting "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when adjusting the code. I also tried taking out the line of code for fv_1 and got "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" again.

Answer (score 0):

The size of fv_1 is 1000 and size of t is 10

The error is here: `plt.plot(t,fv_1,'b-')`

```
print len(t)
print len(fv_1)
print len(fv_2)
print len(fv_3)
```

Output:

```
10
10000
10
10
```

fixing this

```
np.ones(len(t))*pv
```

Answer (score 0):

So I took your advice and wrote in

```
fv_1=np.ones(len(t))*pv.
```

That produced that error: "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Getting rid of:

```
fv_3=pv*pow((1+r),t)
```

and replacing it with its equivalent:

```
fv_3=pv*(1+r)**t
```

generates the correct curves and plot in general.

Thanks again @Roberto Mena & @yper